# MAC OS project upgrades from Fabric to FirebaseCrashlytics (without CoCOPod)

Tags: macos

We need to use Firebase Crashlytics in a project.
We do not use the CocoaPods libraries, and need a statically linked library (.a)
Could you help me with how to download Firebase Crashlytics library into our project?

Here is the error output from the build process:

```
Prepare build
Workspace PDF Reader Pro Edtition | Scheme PDF Reader Pro Edition | Destination My Mac
Using new build system
Building targets in parallel
Planning build
Constructing build description
  Build target PDF Reader Pro Edition
  Project PDF Reader Pro Edtion | Configuration Debug | Destination My Mac | SDK macOS 10.15 
  PDF Reader Pro Edition isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlement...
  OpenGL is deprecated. Consider migrating to Metal instead.
  Building for macOS, but the linked framework 'FirebaseCrashlytics.framework' was built for Mac Catalyst.
  Build failed  2020/6/28, 10:06 AM 2.9 seconds
  1 error, 2 warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub project describes how to build the project without Cocoapods.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Crashlytics

- Clone or download the project.
- Run `Crashlytics/generate_project.sh`
- `open gen/FirebaseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.xcworkspace`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, and the problem has been solved through your help!

Comment: Our company's project MAC application also upgraded to FirebaseCashkit through fabric, but we found a problem. Every time the new MAC system (10.15.5) started, a "YES" file would pop up and could not be opened. After clicking the "OK" button, a request for permission to access a private folder would pop up (sandbox mechanism is used in the project)! I have contacted firebae customer service and he replied that they no longer support Mac related projects! I wonder if I can get the copywriting message or stop it popping up! Is there anything else I need to configure?